# A problem on distance of sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $ A,B,C$ be non empty subsets of $X$.

> If $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) = \inf \{d(x,y) \mid x\in A , y \in B \}$, show that $\mathrm{dist}(A,C) \le \mathrm{dist}(A,B)+ \mathrm{dist}(B,C)$.

Can anyone help me how to show this I thought that it could be easily shown using $d(a,b) \le d(a,c) +  d(c,b) $ but couldn't prove it.

Edit: Thanks for the answers now realize that the statement is false

Comment: This is not right. For example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $A$ is $(-1,0)$, $B$ is $[-1,1]\times \{0\}$, $C$ is $(1,0)$. $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)=0=\mathrm{dist}(B,C)$ but $\mathrm{dist}(A,C)=2$.

Comment: Is $(a,b)$ the open interval or the point? If it's the open interval, then $dist(A,C)=0$

Answer (score 6):

Another example, available in any metric space of cardinality at least two: $d(\{a\},\{b\}) \neq 0$ if $a \neq b$, but $d(\{a\},\{a,b\})=d(\{a,b\},\{b\})=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly false: take (in $\mathbb{R}$, usual distance $d$) $A = [0,1], B = [1,2], C = [2,3]$. Then $\operatorname{dist}(A,B) = \operatorname{dist}(B,C) = 0$, as these sets intersect, but $\operatorname{dist}(A,C) = 1$, from $d(1,2) = 1$.